# Spring Boot - External Tomcat Server Ajax Authentication Failure Message

Tags: ajax, spring, tomcat, authentication, spring-boot

I am using `Spring Boot` to deploy a `.war` file to an `external Tomcat Server`.

I am using `Ajax/Restful` authentication and I have the following class that handles authentication failure:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, exception.getMessage());
}
```

When I'm using the embedded Tomcat server, all goes well and upon authentication failure I get the following JSON:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2015-12-14T15:39:07.365+0000",
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "You have provided wrong credentials",
  "path" : "/api/authentication"
}
```

However, when using an `External Tomcat Server` I get an `HTML` response which brings the usual Tomcat failed authentication page. Is there any way to bypass this for the External Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simply to not use sendError() and to provide a status code and to provide a custom exception serialization:

```
@Service
public class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler
        extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(exception));
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }


}
```